# Is the space of simple functions with finite measure support dense in the weak $L^p$ space

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $(X,\mathcal{X},\mu)$ is a measure space and $1\leq p \leq \infty$. I know that if $p$ is finite or $X$ has finite measure, then the space of simple functions with finite measure support is dense in $L^p(X)$, is it still true for the weak $L^p$ space $L^{p,\infty}(X)$?

Comment: No, in general they are not. See page 4 of these notes http://www.math.ucla.edu/~killip/247a/Lorentz_space_notes.pdf.

Comment: @PhoemueX Thanks. A counterexample is the function $x\mapsto |x|^{-1/p}$, it lies in $L^{p,\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ but cannot be  approximated by simple functions.